# Add multiple/sequential rows - populate DB in Coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How do you insert multiple/sequential new rows in coredata and xcode?

```
-(void)LoadDB{
    CoreDataAppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appdelegate  managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *newPref;        
    newPref = [NSEntityDescription
           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Preference class])
           inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error;

    [newPref setValue: @"0" forKey:@"pid"];      
    [context save:&error];

    [newPref setValue: @"1" forKey:@"pid"];    
    [context save:&error];
}
```

The code above just over writes the previous entry. What is the correct procedure to insert the next row?

Comment: Doc is your friend. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html

Comment: In my experience the apple documentation is more of a cousin you are forced to interact with at family reunions and not really a friend to anybody.

Comment: I try, but it usually just increases my headache exponentially @flexaddicted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a new insert statement for each core data managed object.  Otherwise you are only editing the existing MO.  Also, you only need to save once at the end.

```
-(void)LoadDB{
    CoreDataAppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appdelegate  managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *newPref;
    NSError *error;

    newPref = [NSEntityDescription
               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Preference class])
               inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPref setValue: @"0" forKey:@"pid"];    


    newPref = [NSEntityDescription
               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Preference class])
               inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPref setValue: @"1" forKey:@"pid"];    

    // only save once at the end.
    [context save:&error];
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you should only save at the end of your modifications. This will DRAMATICALLY increase execution time. A few other things to keep in mind to help keep you away from hangups with Core Data in the future. Don't think of core data as a database. It's really not. It's an object graph. Every new entry is a new object that you have to create and link with whatever objects you want (though not every node/object in the graph needs have a link).

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I assumed the:   
    '[context save:&error];'
was the commit. I'm a newb =)

Comment: It is the commit, but you can add a lot to the transaction before ever calling it. You can even reuse the newPref variable over and over like the example above so long as a new insertNewObjectForEntityForName method is called on it.